# How do i know what curl_exec is slow from slow_log

Tags: php-fpm

My applications makes curl fetches html pages using curl.PHP-FPM slowlog shows the following

```
script_filename = /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/www/file.php
[0x00007f2e36a6fdf8] curl_exec() /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/www/file.php:1006
```

The problem is that the page that is fetched by curl is given by the user.How do i find out which specific url was slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instrument your script so that it logs the URL that is being fetched along with the time. Cross reference the time from one log to the other to match entries.